# Need clarification where I am wrong with tree traversal results

Tags: c, tree

So let's say we have the following tree

[image]

What is in-order, post-order, pre-order sequences?

I did manually the following:

in-order: W D V B Y E A C O G K

pre-order: A B D W V E Y C G O K

post-order: W V D Y E B O K G C A

Below is my code and it gives:

In-order:

B D W V E Y A C G O K

Pre-order:

A B D W V E Y C G O K

Post-order:

B D W V E Y C G O K A

Do I have some mistake in my code or I did it manually in a wrong way?
Thank you!

```
struct treenode{
    char c;
    struct treenode *left;
    struct treenode *right;
};

void preOrder(struct treenode *node){
    if(node == NULL) return;
    printf("%c ", node -> c);
    preOrder(node -> left);
    preOrder(node -> right);
    return;
}   


void postOrder(struct treenode *node){
    if(node == NULL) return;
    preOrder(node -> left);
    preOrder(node -> right);
    printf("%c ", node -> c);
    return;
}   

void inOrder(struct treenode *node){
    if(node == NULL) return;
    preOrder(node -> left);
    printf("%c ", node -> c);
    preOrder(node -> right);
    return;
}
```

Comment: typo............Recursively to call themselves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inOrder needs to call itself, not PreOrder.

```
void inOrder(struct treenode *node){
    if(node == NULL) return;
    inOrder(node -> left);
    printf("%c ", node -> c);
    inOrder(node -> right);
    return;
}
```

PostOrder needs to call itself, not PreOrder.

```
void postOrder(struct treenode *node){
    if(node == NULL) return;
    postOrder(node -> left);
    postOrder(node -> right);
    printf("%c ", node -> c);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you are asking really - why doesnt my code emit what I think it should. Answer: because it doesn't

Just follow the flow for the very first character output by in-order

you say it should be W. But walking through the code it goes

in-order(root) => preorder(root->left), and that prints root->left.c which is B

I dont know if inorder first output should be B or W (I dont know enough tree theory) so I cant offer a solutiuon

Answer (score 2):

You have typos:

```
void postOrder(struct treenode *node){
    if(node == NULL) return;
    postOrder(node -> left);  // <-- was pre
    postOrder(node -> right); // <-- was pre
    printf("%c ", node -> c);
    return;
}   

void inOrder(struct treenode *node){
    if(node == NULL) return;
    inOrder(node -> left);    // <-- was pre
    printf("%c ", node -> c);
    inOrder(node -> right);   // <-- was pre
    return;
}
```